# "Unmeaningful to factor" error?

Tags: r

I am staring at this error for some time, but couldn't figure out why. Here's my code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(afterSumPredict)) {
  col<-as.POSIXlt(afterSumPredict[i,1])$wday+1
  row<-rownames(subset(fittedat,fittedat$time==afterSumPredict[i,4]))
  if(afterSumPredict[i,3]<= (0.5 * fittedat[as.numeric(row),col])) {
    afterSumPredict[i,3]<-fittedat[as.numeric(row),col]
  }
}
```

"afterSumPredict" and "fittedat" are both data.frames. I was trying to compare values with the same time column ("col" for day and "row" for time) and replace the value in "afterSumPredict" if it's less than 50% of the value in "fittedat". I got this error message:

> Error in if (afterSumPredict[i, 3] <= (0.5 * fittedat[as.numeric(row),  :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(0.5, fittedat[as.numeric(row), col]) : ‘*’ unmeaningful to factor**

I guess I can't multiply 0.5? `fittedat[as.numeric(row),col]` should be a double. Any idea why it doesn't work? It worked when I just try with i=1,2.. etc, but not within a for-loop.

Comment: `if` isn't vectorized. As for the second message, this isn't reproducible, but you'll have to trust R that `fittedat[as.numeric(row), col]` isn't a numeric/integer vector, so you'll need to debug it. Debug a loop is very easy. `i` is stored in the global environment so you can simply check how `fittedat[as.numeric(row), col]` looks like.

Comment: Hi @David, I tried setting i=1,... and everything worked. Don't know why not working in "if"? And what do you mean "not vectorized"? I think the condition in "if" is only comparing two numbers?

Comment: Don't set `i=1`. just checkout `fittedat[as.numeric(row), col]` after the error occurs.

Comment: I checked again today and just found out as.POSIXlt("Sunday")$wday returned "0" while I thought it would return "7".